# JUnit5 Console launcher does not find any tests in the supplied classpath

Tags: java, junit, junit5

I have downloaded the standalone jar of the JUnit 5 console launcher but I haven't be able to make it work with my code.

Given the file/pkg structure `src/test/java/com/fteotini/dummy/SubjectTest.java`, and the following test class:

```java
package com.fteotini.dummy;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

public class SubjectTest {
    @Test
    void it_runs() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

when running this

```
java -jar junit-platform-console-standalone-1.5.1.jar -cp ./target/test-classes/com/fteotini/dummy --scan-classpath
```

it does not find any test

```
Test run finished after 42 ms
[         2 containers found      ]
[         0 containers skipped    ]
[         2 containers started    ]
[         0 containers aborted    ]
[         2 containers successful ]
[         0 containers failed     ]
[         0 tests found           ]
[         0 tests skipped         ]
[         0 tests started         ]
[         0 tests aborted         ]
[         0 tests successful      ]
[         0 tests failed          ]
```

Comment: I'm not sure so I put it as a comment, have you tried with `--cp` instead of `-cp` ? In their doc they mention it, but honnestly I don't really see why it would work if `-cp` doesn't.

Comment: Have you compiled it? Run `ls ./target/test-classes/com/fteotini/dummy/SubjectTest.class`. If no file name will be displayed, it means you have just not compiled it.

Answer (score 0):

Classpath is wrong. In your case it should be as follows:

`-cp ./target/test-classes`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really don't understand why it should be of any difference. Anyway it does not work with this either.

Comment: @Fed03 The difference is your code is rooted at `.../test-classes`, not `.../test-classes/com/fteotini/dummy`. However, I can't answer why it still doesn't work.